# EncryptionService class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Where can I find `EncryptionService` used in the answer to [Custom Model Binder inheriting from DefaultModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747320/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-model-binder) 
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `System.Security.Cryptography`

Comment: Is a namespace, not a class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Stupid spelling mistake caught me out. That's what you get for cutting and pasting!

Comment: @user1929959 Thanks. That was the missing thing.