# In an MVC4 controller action, how can I validate a model only when it's passed in?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a class as such..

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Test { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm basically trying to achieve this with my controller action..

```
public ActionResult Index(string value1, string value2, TestClass testClass)
{
    if (testClass != null && !ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return validation errors
    }
    //continue processing
```

However due to MVC model binding, `TestClass` is not `null` and therefore it's instantiated containing `null` properties for the strings `Test` and `Test2`, which in turn forces it to check the `ModelState.IsValid` which is of course false.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong or suggest a better alternative?

EDIT.

I'm checking for a null because the requirement is that `value1` and `value2` have to be passed into the system, then the `TestClass` contains extra information on what is being supplied.  The extra information isn't required, however it is supplied it needs to be validated.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If you can explain why you're expecting a null object to be passed in (essentially it isn't in your view).. you might get better answers.

Comment: I've updated the question with a reason for the null checking

Comment: What you're looking for is a `RequiredIf` attribute. There is a NuGet package that contains such an attribute. If you wrap everything in a single ViewModel.. then you can use `RequiredIf` to say that the extra properties are only required if certain other properties are set.

Comment: @ramiramilu the extra information isn't required, however if it is supplied, the properties that it contains need to be validated.  For example if I ask you for your phone number and bank details, you don't have to give me them, however if you do I'll want to validate them.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead that looks interesting thanks and it may be something I'll end up doing, however it seems as though this should be something that MVC should deal with out of the box

Comment: Use Custom Data Annotations also will reach you to your goal, And good point @Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only solution is to use custom model binding (implement [`IModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)).

This gives you full access over the deserialization of the object.

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747320/custom-model-binder-inheriting-from-defaultmodelbinder) on SO and Figure 7 from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx):

Or maybe you can get in between using an [action filter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) (see section Handling Validation Errors).

Comment: Any thoughts on your problem? Did you already find a solution?