# Casting a Parameter into a MVC C# Controller instead of Making a Typed Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller (lets call it Users) and an Action (lets call it AxGetUser) -

I want to pass in an Integer so it looks like:

AxGetUser(int id)

However, if someone passes in a string or ANYTHING else -

I want to be able to capture it and log it as a possible attack attempt.

So I want to know about it.

So if my model is able to make use of the INT I know its a valid integer - but if I get something other than an int - I want to know about it so I can log it and be aware that someone may be trying to manipulate the parameters they are sending to me so that they may attack the system -

What options do I have?

Comment: you could just accept a string or object and immediately do a `int.TryParse()` against it

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly protective, but sure you have a lot of options.

By default ASP.NET MVC model binding will pass in a **0** if someone tries to pass in a string. If you want to see if somebody tried to pass in anything at all you can always look at **Request.Form** or **Request.Params**. The issue is whether the value was Posted or part of the route.

My point is, you always have access to all the data passed in through the **Request** object, model binding is just an abstraction around that.

Comment: This is wrong.  `Method(int id)` if passed a string will result in a `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' ..  An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type...`.  Changing it to an `Method (int? id)` would do as you suggested (but not what the OP stated).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

First Solution: assign a default value for your parameter and if the value is still the default in your code, then voila, you have caught that special case:

```
void AxGetUser(int id = 0)
{
  if( id == 0)
   {
     //you caught him !!
   }
}
```

Second Solution: accept a string parameter and try to parse it. If the parse succeeds, then everything is fine otherwise you have the special case:

```
void AxGetUser(string id)
 {
  if( !int.TryParse(id))
    {
  //you caught him !!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be really careful with this.  You don't want to A. impact valid attempts in a negative way that prevent users from continuing to use your system and B. create a overly complex system that creates an implementation and maintenance nightmare.  I would suggest programming for these *attacks* as an exception and not the rule.  In this case I would build out controllers as you normally would:

```
public ActionResult AxGetUser(int id)
{
}
```

Then I would use [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to log when exceptions occur in my application.

If you happen to know the attack vectors someone might use, you could build your own [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747320/custom-model-binder-inheriting-from-defaultmodelbinder) and throw specific Exceptions that would be logged in Elmah so that you can search for those specific problems.