# @Html.EditorFor doesn't return specific types to the controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's assume the following, simplified, class structure:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : Parent
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class ChildC : Parent
{
    public int NumericData { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Parent> ChildElements { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in my view model I have a list of objects, but these objects can be of different types.

Now, I've found that editor templates work well in this scenario - `@Html.EditorFor()` selects the right editor as needed depending on the type of the element in the list.

I am, however, having trouble getting meaningful data back from the user to the controller. Upon submitting the form, the view-model contains a list of `Parent` elements (not the specific sub-types). Worse - the properties specific to each of the `Child` classes is lost!

What can I do to get all the information for the subtypes back to the controller?

Comment: I'm assume the problem is the `public List<Parent> ChildElements { get; set; }` as far as MVC knows, before the binging occurs it uses the default constructor of parent. Remember that incomming data is Plain/Text. The fact that model binder turns that into objects is to ease the work but if you inspect your request it's all about key value with no metadata, so keep that in mind when dealing with this scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data is posted by to the controller, the MVC framework handles the binding of the request data to your model. Have a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

When it is trying to instantiate your ViewModel, it is probably using the default parameterless constructor for your `Parent` class, and whatever the actual data being sent back, it cannot assign it to the properties as they don't exist within the `Parent` class.

You can create your own [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747320/custom-model-binder-inheriting-from-defaultmodelbinder) which might solve your problem. Or you could potentially create all the properties in the `Parent` class, and have different named EditorTemplates.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Parent, "ChildATemplate")

@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Parent, "ChildBTemplate")
```

As a general rule it is a good idea to stick to the rule, "One View, One ViewModel", even if it feels like duplication at first. It makes it clear exactly what data is being sent out from the server and exactly what data is being returned.

If 'Parent' represents a complex object, perhaps one that that is persisted into a database and is interacted with from several views, then you can always have an intermediate tier which handles converting data from the view model to your complex class.

EDIT - in response to comment regarding survey questions

Rather than using inheritance, why not accept that you need to duplicate a little of the shared values, and create a class for each question type?

```
public class QuestionTypeA 
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionTypeB
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionTypeC
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public int NumericData { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<QuestionTypeA> QuestionAs { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionTypeB> QuestionBs { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionTypeC> QuestionCs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The example I gave was simplified. Imagine you have not 2 or 3 types, but 13 or more. Now you need 13 separate classes (with duplicated properties), 13 lists... and since in the end I need one ordered list, now those lists probably need to be dictionaries or something to keep track of order. It is NOT a reasonable suggestion, in my case, to make each question a specific type and not use inheritance at all. A model binder sounds a lot better and I'm trying that out.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as creating a custom binder is indeed the way to go.